# Multiple inserts using subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, bulkinsert

I have 2 MySQL tables: wp_posts & wp_postmeta. I want to insert multiple values in wp_postmeta determined by the number of rows returned from wp_posts.

I'm using this query:

```
INSERT INTO
  wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES
(
  (SELECT ID
   FROM wp_posts
   WHERE
     post_title
   LIKE '%lorem ipsum%'
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   ), '_tribe_ticket_header', 11719
);
```

The objective of this query is to multiple insert in wp_postmeta the ID given in the subquery, a fixed string and another fixed id.

The query is returning: Subquery returns more than 1 row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **INSERT...SELECT** statements to insert data from another tables.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID, '_tribe_ticket_header', 11719
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_title LIKE '%lorem ipsum%' AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: Thank you so much Saharsh :)